# ajax load not working in ie

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery

ok so I have a portfolio I have to do for a project, the front page is just a div with a loader and when you land on the front page it detects the screen size and chooses what content to pull in with ajax.

I am doing it this way because the iPad/Mobile site is really simple and I didn't have enough time to make another site so its just a really simple version.

My problem is that it does not work in internet explorer at all.
It seems to load the content in, but does not do any of the functions after the load, such as applying plugins and hiding the loader.

I have a feeling its breaking when it starts counting the images, so I was wondering if I could use modernizer to detect if its internet explorer and do a simpler load function, or is there something wrong with my code?

The link to the site is http://chris-g.dmlive.co.nz/

and the load function is as follows

```
function loadSites(){

    var $winHeight = $window.height();  
    var $winWidth = $window.width();    

        if($window.width() >= 1025) {
            // is desktop so load all scripts and set heights to window height
            var $loadCont = $('.full-page');                
            var sourceTarget = '#ninja';
            var pageUrl='http://chris-g.dmlive.co.nz/ninja/';

            $loadCont.load(pageUrl+" "+sourceTarget, function(){

                var $slide = $('.slide');
                var $ninja = $('#ninja');

                //var $imgs = $(this).find("img");
                var $imgs = $ninja.find("img");
                $imgs.hide();
                var loadCounter = 0;
                var nImages = $imgs.length;
                $imgs.load(function () {
                    loadCounter++;
                    if(nImages === loadCounter) {

                        // all the images have loaded
                        // reveal them, remove the loading indicator
                        $imgs.show(); 
                        $slide.css({'height':$winHeight});  
                        $('#ninja-content').show();
                        $('.page-loader').fadeOut(500);                         
                        $ninja.interactiveScrolling();
                        $('#intro').parallaxScrolling();
                        $('#contact-form').formValidation();                            
                        $('#portfolio').portfolioAnimations();
                        callPopAnimations();

                    }

                // trigger load event if images have
                // been cached by the browser
                }).each(function () {
                    if(this.complete) {
                        $(this).trigger("load");   
                    }
                }); 

            }), function(){

            };  // end ajax load

        } else {
            // is a touch device so load in the stripped back site
            var $loadCont = $('.full-page');                
            var sourceTarget = '#basic-content';
            var pageUrl='http://chris-g.dmlive.co.nz/basic-page/';

            $loadCont.load(pageUrl+" "+sourceTarget, function(){

                var $basicContent = $('#basic-content');

                //var $imgs = $(this).find("img");
                var $imgs = $basicContent.find("img");
                $imgs.hide();
                var loadCounter = 0;
                var nImages = $imgs.length;
                $imgs.load(function () {
                    loadCounter++;
                    if(nImages === loadCounter) {

                        // all the images have loaded
                        // reveal them, remove the loading indicator
                        $imgs.show(); 
                        $('#portfolio').loadProjectBasic();
                        $('#contact-form').formValidation();    
                        $('.page-loader').fadeOut(500);
                        $('#ninja-content').show();
                    }

                // trigger load event if images have
                // been cached by the browser
                }).each(function () {
                    if(this.complete) {
                        $(this).trigger("load");   
                    }
                }); 

            }); // end ajax load

        }   // end if window width  

}   // end loadSites
```

Comment: use the right doctype http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: What is wrong the my doctype?
I am using the html5 boilerplate, so im not quite sure what you mean

Comment: You tried `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`? IE is a pain in the a**

Comment: I checked your site in IE 9 on 64 bits and i see the page correctly AFTER using the compatibility view.

Comment: Ok so I just tested it with the the doctype above and it did not work, but yeah it works when I use the compatibility view option, still no good, really not sure of what is going on here

Comment: I just took out the image counting function that is inside the load function and it loads everything fine, the thing is I still want this for other browsers.

Would it be possible to detect if it was any IE platform and put another if statement in there with the load function without the image counter?

Comment: Yes there is the `<!--[if IE *]-->` for HTML. Putt javascript within. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I ended up making a variable in the head and decided that if you were using internet explorer you would not get the preloading, kind of hacky but needed to get it done as it was a site for a school assignment.

```
<script>isExplorer = false;</script>    
<!--[if IE]>
    <script>isExplorer = true;</script>
<![endif]-->    

and then adding an if statement to my jQuery 

    function loadSites(callback){

        var $winHeight = $window.height();  
        var $winWidth = $window.width();    

            if($window.width() >= 1025) {
                // is desktop so load all scripts and set heights to window height
                var $loadCont = $('.full-page');                
                var sourceTarget = '#ninja';
                var pageUrl='http://chrisgjones.com/ninja/';

                $loadCont.load(pageUrl+" "+sourceTarget, function(){

                    var $slide = $('.slide');
                    var $ninja = $('#ninja');
                    var $ninjaCont = $('#ninja-content');
                    var $pageLoader = $('.page-loader');                    
                    var $intro = $('#intro');
                    var $contactForm = $('#contact-form');
                    var $portfolio = $('#portfolio');

                    if(isExplorer == true){


                        //alert('is ie');
                        $slide.css({'height':$winHeight});  
                        $ninjaCont.show();
                        $ninja.interactiveScrolling();
                        $intro.parallaxScrolling();
                        $contactForm.formValidation();                          
                        $portfolio.loadProjectBasic();
                        //callPopAnimations();
                        $pageLoader.hide();                                                 

                    }else if(isExplorer == false){

                        //alert('is not ie');
                        //var $imgs = $(this).find("img");
                        var $imgs = $ninja.find("img");
                        $imgs.hide();
                        var loadCounter = 0;
                        var nImages = $imgs.length;
                        $imgs.load(function () {
                            loadCounter++;
                            if(nImages === loadCounter) {

                                // all the images have loaded
                                // reveal them, remove the loading indicator
                                $imgs.show(); 
                                $slide.css({'height':$winHeight});  
                                $ninjaCont.show();
                                $ninja.interactiveScrolling();
                                $intro.parallaxScrolling();
                                $contactForm.formValidation();                          
                                $portfolio.portfolioAnimations();
                                callPopAnimations();
                                //$('.page-loader').hide();     
                                callback.call();                                                    

                            }   // end counter

                        // trigger load event if images have
                        // been cached by the browser
                        }).each(function () {
                            if(this.complete) {
                                $(this).trigger("load");   
                            }   // end cache trigger load
                        }); // end each 

                    }   // end if is explorer or good browser

                }); // end load

            } else {
                // is a touch device so load in the stripped back site
                var $loadCont = $('.full-page');                
                var sourceTarget = '#basic-content';
                var pageUrl='http://chrisgjones.com/basic-page/';

                $loadCont.load(pageUrl+" "+sourceTarget, function(){

                    var $basicContent = $('#basic-content');

                    //var $imgs = $(this).find("img");
                    var $imgs = $basicContent.find("img");
                    $imgs.hide();
                    var loadCounter = 0;
                    var nImages = $imgs.length;
                    $imgs.load(function () {
                        loadCounter++;
                        if(nImages === loadCounter) {

                            // all the images have loaded
                            // reveal them, remove the loading indicator
                            $imgs.show(); 
                            $('#portfolio').loadProjectBasic();
                            $('#contact-form').formValidation();    
                            $('.page-loader').hide();
                            $('#ninja-content').show();
                        }

                    // trigger load event if images have
                    // been cached by the browser
                    }).each(function () {
                        if(this.complete) {
                            $(this).trigger("load");   
                        }   // end cache trigger load
                    }); // end each

                }); // end ajax load

            }   // end if window width  

    }   // end loadSites
```